# Django Rest Framework SerializerMethodField TypeError: "'RelatedManager' object does not support indexing"

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two SerializerMethodFields on a serializer.  One of them returns obj.somelist.count() fine.  But where I am asking the other method to return obj.somelist[0] I'm getting a TypeError 'RelatedManager' object does not support indexing.  Any advice is much appreciated.
Here's some code:

```
class TripPlaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = TripPlace
        fields = ('trip', 'place', )


class StopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = TripPlace
        fields = ('place', )
        depth = 1


class TripSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    stops = StopSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    stops_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    car = CarSerializer(read_only=True, many=False)
    origin = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    # final = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Trip
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'owner', 'car', 'stops_count', 'stops', 'origin', )

    def get_stops_count(self, obj):
        return obj.stops.count()

    def get_origin(self, obj):
        return obj.stops.first()
```

Answer (score 5):

`obj.somelist` is the `RelatedManager` for whatever the underlying relationship is, you can't index it directly. You should call the `first` method of the `RelatedManager` to get the first object:

```
def get_origin(self, obj):
    return obj.somelist.first()
```

Or you can index(or slice) a queryset of the manager using a different index different from `0`:

```
def get_origin(self, obj):
    return obj.somelist.all()[ind]
```

Comment: ```.first()``` returns the first stop instance, but now the model representing the join table between a trip and a place which is what the StopSerializer is just with a depth of 1 is returning Object of type "TripPlace" is not serializable.  Updated code ^.  It was rendering fine before.

Comment: @alirk Sorry pal, if the answer fixes your original problem, you may consider asking a new one.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)